# How to define large list of strings in Visual Basic

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm writing a macro in Visual Basic for PowerPoint 2010. I'd like to initialize a really big list of strings like:

```
big_ol_array = Array( _
"string1", _
"string2", _
"string3", _
"string4" , _
  .....
"string9999" _
)
```

...but I get the "Too many line continuations" error in the editor. When I try to just initialize the big array with no line breaks, the VB editor can't handle such a long line (1000+) characters.

Does anyone know a good way to initialize a huge list of strings in VB?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not use collection or dictionary ?

Comment: One way is to keep the list in an excel spreadsheet and just read in the range as an array.

Comment: You don't need an "all or nothing" approach. You could include more values on a line, reducing the number of line continuation characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do what you want. But there exist some workarounds.

For example, you could load your list of strings from a file. 
That example can show you a hint :

`Dim value As String = File.ReadAllText("C:\file.txt")`

Also, this page talks about it : [Excel macros - Too many line continuations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806151/excel-macros-too-many-line-continuations).

Comment: You cannot declare and initialize variable in one line using vba.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on [freelax's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23876639/3198973):

You could store the string values in an external text file and read the items into an array line by line. My example (untested) early binds to the **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** library.

```
Dim arr() as string
Dim fso as New FileSystemObject
Dim fl as file
Dim ts as textstrean
Dim i as long ' counter

Set fl = fso.GetFile("c:\path\to\configfile.txt")
Set ts = fl.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
i = 0
Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
    Redim Preserve arr(i) 'resize the array leaving data in place
    arr(i) = ts.Readline
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Further Reading:

1. [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706(v=vs.60).aspx)
2. [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242698(v=vs.60).aspx)
3. [TextStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242724(v=vs.60).aspx)
4. [Reading a text file with
   vba](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/2013/09/12/read-txt-file-using-vba/comment-page-1/)
5. [Redim an array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx)

Of course, you'll probably want to be smarter about resizing the array, doubling it's size when you run out of space.

Answer (score 1):

An option for a workaround might be to use the `Join` Command, like this:

```
Const ARRAY_VALUES As String = _
"string1,string2," & _
"string3,string4"

Dim big_ol_array() As String
big_ol_array() = Split(ARRAY_VALUES, ",")
```

This would allow you to put multiple entries on each line, and then you could use multiple lines continuations.

Or, if you really want one value per line, you could just use multiple constants, like this:

```
Const ARRAY_VALUES1 As String = _
"string1," & _
"string2," & _
"string3," & _
"string4,"

Const ARRAY_VALUES2 As String = _
"string5," & _
"string6," & _
"string7," & _
"string8"

Const ARRAY_VALUES As String = _
ARRAY_VALUES1 & _
sARRAY_VALUES2
```

Of course, you could choose a different delimiter if it conflicts with your data. In cases like this I'll use a pretty rare but readable delimiter like the bullet (`•`), which can be typed by holding the Alt key and typing the "0149" on the number pad. Then your code would look like this:

```
Const ARRAY_VALUES As String = _
"string1•string2•" & _
"string3•string4"

Dim big_ol_array() As String
big_ol_array() = Split(ARRAY_VALUES, "•")
```

Here's some other *interesting* delimiters. These will all show up in the IDE (while others will just look like a box):

§ ¸ · • ¤ « » ¦ ± _­ ¯ ¨ ª ¹ ² ³ ´ ° º ¿ ¡

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the line continuation character as what GSerg posted in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806151/excel-macros-too-many-line-continuations) if you want to keep it simple. Same link posted by Freelex actually.

```
Dim bigStr As String, big_ol_array() As String

bigStr = "string1"
bigStr = bigStr & "," & "string2"
bigStr = bigStr & "," & "string3"
.
.
bigStr = bigStr & "," & "string9999"
big_ol_array() = Split(bigStr, ",")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim BigOlArray(1 to 99999) as String
BigOlArray(1) = "String1"
BigOlArray(2) = "String2"
```

or to save some typing

```
' Keep copy/pasting the second and third lines as needed
' then all you need to change is the string
x = 1
BigOlArray(x) = "String1"
x = x+1
BigOlArray(x) = "String2"
x = x+1
BigOlArray(x) = "String3"
x = x+1
```